# Ubuntu - Server closes connections in 2 minutes after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, mysql

First of all, hello to everyone as it's my first post here. Until now, all of my questions have been already asked and answered :) not this time unfortunately.

I have a VPS (Ubuntu 14.04 32bit, 2 GB mem) which is my "sandbox". I test my PHP/MySQL application and learn to use and manage Linux server. Since about a week MYSQL performed quite slow. It took a few seconds for a SELECT (no JOINs) in a ~2 million records table.

Today, I found some time to take care of it and to look for a problem. I've read a few discussions on MySQL optimisation. I found out via SolusVM control panel that server uses 100% memory.
I tried **top** to check what process consumes most of memory but it didn't sum up to 100%. The largest process was MySQL with about 33% of memory.

I rebooted the server and after first reboot it closes all connections in ~2 minutes.
**After each reboot in ~2 minutes I get:**

- an error in Putty "*Server unexpectedly closed netword connection*".
- any domain hosted on that server returns "*connection timeout error*"
- WinSCP tries to connect to server and returns no error, starts over and over again to make a connection

In syslog file I have no info about problems - just an info that mysql tables need an update.

In these 2 minutes between log in (via Putty) and closing connection by server I tried to stop some services, like mysql, cron, postfix, apache and proftpd. After each test one by one server was closing connection in ~2 minutes after reboot - so it had no impact on server behaviour.

What I've noticed watching Memory Usage in SolusVM control panel. When the connections are closed, the memory usage drops from ~40% to ~20% and than in a few seconds increases to ~50% and later in a few minutes it reaches 100%.

What else can I check to find out what happens in these 2 minutes after reboot?

---

EDIT:

I need to also add that since my last login to the server in the root directory appeared "aquota.group" and "aquota.user" files. I don't understand why yet. But tried **quotaoff** command. After this, server closed connections in ~2 minutes after reboot - so...nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour or so from last reboot, server started to repond and to accept connections but memory usage was at 100%.
I've just found the problem. One of scripts executed every minute by CRON saves its result to a log file which grew to almost 8 GB.
**I deleted file's contents and memory usage dropped to ~50%.**

I've just rebooted the server once again and...everything seems to work just fine.
Looks like **the script I've mentioned before was trying to open the large file but server lacked in memory to do it**. I'm just wondering how was it able to open it before and let it grow to such a large size...